# Module library dependancies is not working

Tags: 8

I have a module that is loading a custom library. In that library I'm trying to set jquery and drupalSettings as dependancies, but they are not being loaded. Here is my library and code:

in questionnaire.libraries.yml:

```
google_map:
  version: 1.1
  css:
    theme:
      css/google_map.css: {}
  js:
    js/google_map.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupalSettings
```

in the QuestionnaireController:

```
$element['#attached']['library'][] = 'questionnaire/google_map';
```

I get this error when loading the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I know the library is being loaded, because it is picking up on the javascript and css I have made. I'm assuming the dependencies are not being loaded, since that error means jquery is not being loaded. Any specific reason why I can't load dependancies from the core?

Comment: What if you replace the $ by jQuery ?

Comment: Most likely your custom JS is not wrapped in (function($) { code.. })(jQuery());

Comment: I tried that @IvanJaros and it didn't work. If I enter the element inspector and search for jquery, it's no where to be found. I ended up including jquery in the beginning of the twig file and it works for now... but I would like to get it working using the drupal way.

Comment: As you said, the library works, so it has to be a problem with your JS code, which you need to post so that we can help you. Note that it's jQuery, not jquery, javascript and the console are case sensitive.